# WebApi Call hits Constructor but not my Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a number of Web Services using `WebAPI2` using `.Net 4.5.2`, and when testing this locally I call my API from Restlet client in Chrome but get a 404 Error.

When adding a break point in both my method and my constructor the breakpoint in my constructor is hit, but not my method.  However, there is a message handler that is doing my authentication on an API key that is also being hit and it is breaking on this.

If I remove the message handler async method I still get the same issue so I dont think it is this.

I am calling my method as follows

http://localhost:51516/api/I306/I306ProcessDataFile

The method that I am working with is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("I306ProcessDataFile")]
public string ProcessData()
{
    var files = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys;
    if (files.Length == 0)
    {
        _result.Success = false;
        _result.Message = _eh.ErrorMessages(ErrorCodes.NoFilesReceived, null);
        _result.StatusCode = 500;
        return GetXmlFromObject.GetXMLFromObject(_result);
    }

    var model = new List<I306Model>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                BuildModelList(file, model);
                foreach (var item in model)
                {
                    _dtSupplier.Rows.Add(
                        item.Cont_Code,
                        item.Cont_Code_Purch,
                        item.Supplier_Code_txt,
                        item.Supplier_Code
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(_dtSupplier);

        return _i306.RunSqlUpdates(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _result.Success = false;
        _result.Message = _eh.ErrorMessages(ErrorCodes.ApplicationError, ex, ex.Message);
        _result.StatusCode = 500;
        return GetXmlFromObject.GetXMLFromObject(_result);
    }
}
```

Any and all help on whats going wrong is very much appreciated

Comment: 1. Are you actually using POST in your test? 2. Where is the `/I306/` coming from in your URL?

Comment: aren't you missing `api` in your route, so rather `[Route("api/I306/I306ProcessDataFile")]`. Did you check the message that returns in the response of the failed request? Something like, cannot find a matching endpoint on the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create full api path;

```
[Route("api/I306/I306ProcessDataFile")]
```

Comment: Not necessarily. He could have a `[RoutePrefix("api/I306")]` on the controller class

Comment: Yes, it is an another and simple option.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth But that is just playing a guessing game, no :) I agree that the OP should give more detail :)

Comment: @Icepickle: Absolutely agree

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the question as accepted if it worked.